# Why can my index seek estimate the right number of rows and the sort operator can't?

Tags: sql-server, index, statistics

I've a query that uses a function on the predicate, something like this:

```
commentType = 'EL'
AND commentDateTime >= DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()) - 13,0)
```

I have a filtered index on commentType that has 40K rows and when I run the query, the estimated number of rows for the Index Seek is very accurate (around 11K), but for the next step (sort operator) it completely ignores the statistics and just estimates the total number of rows in the filtered index.

Why is this happening? I know the basics about [sargability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), and I've tested just for the sake of sanity replacing the dateadd by an actual date (2014-01-01) and voila... The sort started guessing the number of rows correctly...

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I can't pass a fixed date...

Comment: `DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()) - 13,0)` doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to do with this? May it could be improved/simplified?

Comment: @Daniel That's the beginning of the month, 13 months ago.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to reflect the version of SQL Server (?) you're on. Use tags for that.

Comment: Could you try `DATEADD(month, -13, DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(day, SYSDATETIME()))` and see if there's any difference?

Comment: If you have a non-filtered index on `(commentType, commentDate)`, does it behave better there? It's just that filtered indexes can sometimes misreport estimates at different points in plans. The estimate seems way out by reporting the total number in the filtered index, but it's actually that the plan is being shown wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I believe your estimates are wrong because of an estimator bug that swaps two of the DATEDIFF arguments. I talk about this here:

- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : DATEDIFF](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug)

A workaround is to calculate the first day of 13 months ago without using DATEDIFF (2008+):

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -13, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));
```

I'm not *positive* that will address the estimate (I haven't tested with filtered indexes, and I'm not sure what the sort is actually doing or why it has a different estimate without the plan and/or the rest of the query).

The fix Microsoft recommends is to use TF 4199, but I'm not so sure that's what you'll need to do here:

- [Connect #630583 : Incorrect estimate with condition that includes > datediff](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff)

Another option would be to make sure you're on the absolute latest SP/CU for whatever version of SQL Server you're using, as they claim it is fixed in the following KB article (though this will still require the use of TF 4199 unless you are on 2014 or better):

- [KB #2481274 : FIX: A query that uses the DATEDIFF function may run slowly in SQL Server 2005 or in SQL Server 2008 or in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2481274)

The fix can be obtained with the following builds:

- [2005 SP3 CU 15](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507766) (>= 9.00.4325 AND <= 9.00.4999)
- [2005 SP4 CU 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2489409) (>= 9.00.5259)
- [2008 SP1 CU 13](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2497673) (>= 10.00.2816.00 AND <= 10.00.3999)
- [2008 SP2 CU 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2498535) (>= 10.00.4279.00 AND <= 10.00.5499)
- By extension 2008 SP3 & SP4 (>= 10.00.5500)
- [2008 R2 CU 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507770) (10.50.1777.0)
- [2008 R2 SP1 CU 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2544793) (>= 10.50.2769.0 AND <= 10.50.3999)
- By extension 2008 R2 SP2 & SP3 (>= 10.50.4000)
- By extension 2012, 2014, 2016 (>= 11.0)

*(Next time, please include the results of `SELECT @@VERSION` in your question.)*

I will note that the KB article says that DATEDIFF can **underestimate** the number of rows, which is the opposite of what is happening in your scenario. That doesn't mean the fixes don't apply to you; I think the KB article wording is inaccurate, as the estimates can go either way depending on the data and the range you're looking at.

My blog post above confirmed that the swapping no longer occurs in 2014 and up. To be safe, I would probably just scrap DATEDIFF from your predicate and use a different method to calculate the beginning of your range. I don't suggest the overkill of 4199 or using dynamic SQL to prevent the bad swap.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I tried your suggestion and the plan changed.
This is how it was before : http://s16.postimg.org/t5j6o1yed/fix_wrong.png
This is how it is after i changed my datediff by yours : http://postimg.org/image/5f725rj83/

I'm going to read all the urls you gave me. 

Cheers.